# How to launch an ionic web app - where should ionic server be running?

Tags: cordova, mobile, web, ionic-framework

I am building an ionic app for prototyping purposes. For the first version I want it to simply be a web based app. I know how to run the app locally on my computer - I simply type ionic serve and the app runs. However, to actually have remote clients, I am not sure how to run this app. DO I need to have the ionic server running at a port on my main server, and then have the clients all make requests to that port on the server IP address?
How do I actually do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just take everything from your `www` folder and place it on your web server. That's all there is to it.

Say your web server address is `bharat.com` and say you placed the `www` folder in your web server root. In that case, your Ionic app will be visible at `bharat.com/www`.

Comment: Ok so say I put it into bharat.com/www, then after that I have to do the folowing on my server right? ionic serve --address bharat.com

Comment: No. Once you put it on your server, you don't have to run `ionic serve`. Because, `ionic serve` does this actually locally for you. But, on the actual web server, you don't have to.